# Pythonic way of selecting specific region of datatframe based off sign and position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (hundreds of rows) that oscillates about zero with sinusoidal motion.
When I call my data the most recent datapoints are either tracing out a peak or a valley, and cant be used for my purposes since it is not complete peak or valley.

What I need to do is find the previous complete peak or valley, and return it as a separate dataframe.

Some code illustrating what im trying to do is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3.7, 3.5, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -6.3, -6, -5.9, -5.3, -5, -4, -3, -2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3,
     2, 1, -1, -2], columns=list('T'))

plt.plot(data)
plt.axhline(y=0.0, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

Plotting this returns
[image: Output]

So since the most recent data is negative, I need to return the circled area as it is the most recent complete valley.

So in this example I'd like to return previous_valley as a dataframe

```
previous_valley = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -6.3, -6, -5.9, -5.3, -5, -4, -3, -2]
```

When I call the data it could also be tracing a peak, so I also need a way to find the most recent complete peak too

Currently I can find the data Im after by reversing the dataframe, and iterating through it discarding values until i'm at the peak or valley I need (lots of looping) , but I'll be the first to admit its not very efficient or pythonic so I was hoping someone can point me to a more efficient way.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean, are you searching for the last valley? because the last peak is not what you are saying in this graph

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I am looking for the last valley. Since the most recent data (from 30 on ) is forming a valley, I'd like the find the most recent complete valley (from 10 to 23) please let me know if that makes sense

Comment: @user176301 Please explain question using the input dataframe you already  provided in  code. and  Is this asking to split the dataframe?

Comment: @PandaKim Since the blue line is below zero at the right side of the graph, im trying to return the previous valley. so in the example I need a new dataframe from 10 to 23 that has all the negative numbers in it

Comment: I edited the question to add an expected out put please let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
cond1 = data['T'].eq(0)
s = data['T'].mask(cond1).bfill()
grp = s.mul(s.shift()).lt(0).cumsum() # divide group by peak, valley

# find max group number of valley (except uncomplete valley)
target = grp[data['T'].lt(0) & grp.lt(grp.max())].max() 
# boolean indexing max groupy number of valley
out = data[grp.eq(target) & ~cond1]
```

out:

```
      T
10  -1.0
11  -2.0
12  -3.0
13  -4.0
14  -5.0
15  -6.0
16  -6.3
17  -6.0
18  -5.9
19  -5.3
20  -5.0
21  -4.0
22  -3.0
23  -2.0
```

---

chk with other example

```
data = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2], columns=['T'])
```

data:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

out:

```
[-1, -2, -3, -2, -1]
```